# Android - Update contacts without using Intent

Tags: android, edit, contacts

Please  help me, I am  trying to update a contact by CONTACT_ID or by NAME. The only way i got it to work is with using Intent, but I want it to  be updated in the background thread.

These are the code snippets I tried:

```
try {
    String newName = "test";
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=? AND " +
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
                    new String[]{"Alexa Prg"})
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, newName)
            .build());
    ContentProviderResult[] result = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Do Any thing
}
```

and

```
Activity context = new Activity();


try {
    ContentResolver contentResolver  = context.getContentResolver();

    ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
    ops.add(android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=? AND " +
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
                    new String[]{"560"})    //ID
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, newName)
            .build());

    contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

} catch (Exception e) {


}
```

Both the snippets aren't working

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? Did you get any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: From where your pass context you have to pass context `Activity context = new Activity();` if you use like this it won't work

Comment: `Context context = this.getContext();`

Comment: i dont get any errors, it just dosent update

Comment: Context context = this.getContext(); 
this says 'cannot resolve getContext();'